# How to add new rows to the top in datagrid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in which Im adding row values in runtime. Each new row is added below the previous row. I want to add newest row on top. When a new row is added I want the previous row to be below the new one.

I also need some help in deleting the oldest row once the row count reaches 100, so that my DGV will always have 100 rows no matter how many rows I add. I tried this by  doing this, but it always gives me an index out of range error:

```
            if (dataGridView4.Rows.Count >= 99)
            {
                dataGridView4.Rows.RemoveAt(0); //also tried 98
            }
```

Comment: Please keep to one question when asking for assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a new row is added I want the previous row to be below the new one.

For a DataGridView that does not have it's DataSource property set use the [Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.insert?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method.

On the other hand, let's say DataSource of the DataGridView is set to a DataTable than use SomeDataTable.Rows.[InsertAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat?view=net-6.0).

And in either case a current sort may affect the actual final position of the inserted row.

Comment: Thanks, Adding rows by using Insert(0, data) worked. Instead of adding new rows to 0, I was using an increment integer. This also fixed the delete issue, now the old rows are getting deleted too. Thanks again.

Comment: For old rows are getting deleted, start a new question please.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind your `DataGridView` with source collection .Try adding new item by inserting item in source such as this code

```
datalist.Insert(0, item)
```